# How can I animate an iPhone screen within a blender animation?

Tags: after-effects

I rendered an iPhone with a black screen in Blender and then animated it so the camera pans in a circle around the iPhone. I exported this as an AVI file. Then I took my real iPhone and took a screen recording. How can I use After Effects to overlay the black screen from the fake rendered iPhone with this recording while the AVI video pans the camera around the rendered phone? I am new to After Effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your screen recording as a video texture in Blender.

This would then require no tracking / layering in After Effects. 
Here's an [example](https://youtu.be/nxMCZ8ezna4?t=83) of how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

I made an attempt to use a green screen my rendering the iphone again with a green front and then using track motion within After Effects. Results aren't great, it doesn't track well and it's very wobbly but it seems like I'm on the right track.